# How do we manage the duplication of information that is already curated on Meta.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Already, we're getting questions like ["What can I do when getting..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) here on Meta.SO.

While our new fledgling meta is still small and manageable, can we come to a consensus about what to do with these questions?   We can't close them as dupes, because they are not on this site, and I can't migrate and close unilaterally, because I don't have moderator privileges on Meta.StackExchange.

I'm not sure that we want to duplicate all of that information here, just to have targets for dup closure, and I don't necessarily want to just dump these questions on Meta.StackExchange without the ability to take care of the dup closure myself.

Comment: [And cross site duplicates, even for meta, has so far not been accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225047/cross-site-duplicates-in-meta).  Even though I think that, from an entirely conceptual standpoint, it makes sense for any site-specific meta to close questions as a duplicate of any meta.SE question.

Comment: This surely can't be unique to MSO. How are other child Metas dealing with the same issue? Any idea?

Comment: Relevant: [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) (it didn't really kick off apparently, my question is the only one under [meta-tag:faq-proposed])

Comment: We can fill up that FAQ index with links to the Meta.SE questions, but it doesn't solve the "close as duplicate problem," unless we think that the index itself is a viable duplication target.  That would be a stretch, though.

Comment: It would be great if typing in a question would not only bring up search results for MSO, but also bring up results for MSE.

Comment: @Bart Usually someone types up an answer including a bunch of MSE links as references.  It's still not quite ideal though.

Comment: I think that one of the best ways to solve this would be to have a "mark as duplicate on Meta.SE" close reason in the dialog (with Meta.SE suggestions) for every meta site. This (a) makes it easy for non-mods to help out (no migration) and (b) also makes Meta.SE more of an inclusive, refer-to-the-canon-question type site, which is exactly what it should be. I know it will be more work for the developers, but something like this could really solve the whole issue of per-site duplicates of canon questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

For now, do what any other Meta site would do. Write an answer pointing to the Meta.SE version of the answer, along with a brief summary if possible, then close all other copies of the question as a duplicate of that one.

And for the future, I would like to ask SE that we be allowed to close meta questions as duplicates to Meta.SE questions.

Comment: I feel like that could be a lot of work. Not impossible, but it would be nice if we dont need to have another copy of MSE.

Comment: @DGrin91 except some SE sites might not work like MSE assumes all SE sites work.  Do we have blocks on individual metas that say "we know about blah on MSE, but here we do it differently" for each?  Or do we have pointers on each SE to MSE for things that are covered on MSE but asked locally?

Comment: @Dgrin91 Its no more work than normal, and its probably better to have a copy on Meta.SO instead of trying to direct every newcomer to Meta.SE and explaining the difference between the sites repeatedly. Just answer questions like that as needed when they come up, and be sure to link to the related Meta.SE post so there's always a pointer to the up-to-date copy in case anything changes.

Comment: This does bring up an interesting point... Do we really need every frequently-asked question endlessly duplicated on the child metas?

Comment: @Robert - I hope not, especially considering how easy cross site duplicate closure should in principle be to implement

Comment: @Rachel Its definitely more work to write a custom response AND point to a MSE post than to just flag as a duplicate which does a lot of stuff automatically for you.

Comment: @Yakk I dont understand what your comment is saying.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In the short term this is not a bad option - having a placeholder question here is useful because it will show up in the *Possible Duplicates* and *Similar Questions* list.

Comment: In lieu of a cross-site flagging/duplicate link feature this is a semantically correct approach because it is an external resource.

Comment: Here is an example: [*Stack Overflow timezone*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255112/109702)

Answer (score 1):

I think we need a new off-topic close reason:

> This question concerns a subject that is common to all Stack Exchange sites. The correct place to ask such questions is [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

I'd like to see such questions very quickly closed and forgotten about. Duplication of FAQ info is evil.

While cross-site duplicates would solve the problem, I don't feel it should be the responsibility of users of this site to provide links to answers on other sites. Pointing them to the other site should be sufficient.

I think there is a temptation to treat this site differently because it was once the meta site for all of SE. We should try and forget that and treat questions like any other site would treat them. Off topic? Close and forget.

Comment: But they're not really off topic. They're duplicates. I suggested overloading the "Off Topic -> Other" reason only as a stopgap until the devs get us a proper cross-site duplicate mechanism.

Comment: @BrockAdams I believe they are off-topic. This site is for questions relating only to Stack Overflow and not all SE sites.

Comment: IIRC, it was already established, elsewhere in Meta-land ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225047) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708) and ???), that they *are* on topic. Hence part of the problem that prompted the OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it would be EVIL to duplicate all those posts.

How about we agree to:

1. For now, **Close as *Off Topic* -> *Other*** with comments like:
   **This topic already covered by {link to a Meta.StackExchange post}**

   Hopefully this is just a stopgap until step 3 bears fruit.  The posts are not strictly off topic, but this is the closest *current* mechanism I could see that allows us to handle these duplicates sensibly.
2. Also comment the question to provide the Meta.StackExchange link, so that users can more easily know to close-vote (or flag, if they don't have the rep). They could also search for such questions.
3. **Continue to pester the devs for a "Close as a duplicate of a Meta.StackExchange post" feature.**