# Stack Overflow timezone

Tags: support, timezone

What timezone does Stack Overflow record date/time of questions and comments in?

Comment: The relevant question on meta.se: [What time zone do SO's servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42179)

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Please add that as an answer (even though it is short it is still the correct answer). Future dupe questions can then be linked to this one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because while it does mention Stack Overflow the answer pertains to the entire Stack Exchange network and an answer already exists on Meta.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything is calculated in [UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

You can actually see the current Stackoverflow time when clicking on the achievement/rep change menu item on the MultiCollider top bar:

[image]

This has been answered in [What time zone do SO's servers operate in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42179) and verified by @Pops in the comments.